# How to get a custom toolbar aligned with the action bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, imagebutton

In order to get action-buttons into my toolbar, I have implemented a custom-toolbar in which the layout with the button images can be defined. In the activity_main layout file, I refer to this custom-toolbar layout via an include instruction.

It works to the extend that now in 1 line at the top of the action bar both contents appear: My program title and the overflow menu icon PLUS the button from the custom-toolbar. The problem is that below this line a second empty row appears with no content. Means, the height of the action bar is doubled and this unwanted area is overlapping my canvas. Here the screenshot of the phenomena:

[image: On the device]

I have searched for documents addressing this but did not find a mapping case. Furthermore I have tried all kind of constellations in my layout file (e.g. in respect to the postion of the include instruction) but did not achieve a Change. I also tried with different sizes of the image file without a Change. The current size is 3K with 80x49 Pixel.

Here my code which is reduced to show just the case relevant lines:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void on_distance_waiting_Click(View view) {
     }

}
```

The main layout:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.pm.pmactionbaricon.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"  />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The custom-toolbar layout:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        >


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:background="@drawable/distance_waiting_small"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:title="@string/Distance"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:onClick="on_distance_waiting_Click"/>

     </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

The style file:

```
    <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>
    </style>
 </resources>
```

Here also the used Image:[image]

When I work with the Layouts in the design mode, I can recognize that the regular toolbar element (not the custom-toolbar) seems to be responsible for the unwanted area. The following 3 screenshots might help to Highlight this. It is also strange that the appearance here is different from the result on the device as shown at the beginning.

The activity layout (consider what is selected in the right window):
[image]

The activity layout with (Standard) toolbar selected:
[image]

The custom toolbar:
[image]

So, what is causing this unwanted area below the actionbar?

Comment: You have included toolbar twice in the layout. Just remove it. I'll include an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity_main.xml remove the extra toolbar element:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.pm.pmactionbaricon.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In custom_toolbar.xml layout make changes as shown below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:padding="0dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:background="@drawable/distance_waiting_small"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:title="@string/Distance"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:onClick="on_distance_waiting_Click"/>

     </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Also, make sure that your activity tag has this attribute set in the manifest file.

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. With your advice I was able to achieve my plan in the sample program which I had created for the problem demonstration.  Your answer was just right. However, when trying to apply this now to my main application I cannot succeed even though I have identical code as far theme, design and layout are concerned, except that in the main layout file I have to use two fragments. I do not have double actionbar in heights but have two problems: a) The custom toolbar covers the original. I get no title and menu. b) the custom toolbar overlays the upper canvas.

Comment: Sorry, I have to correct my message above. In the mean time I found a mistake I made: In my main program, I had forgotten to insert the commands for      Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);  in OnCreate.     After having done this, problem a) above is resolved. Means, I get a proper toolbar with my buttons displayed. Thanks! What remains is that the custom toolbar overlaps the canvas. E.g. in case I would draw a circle on the canvas, it's upper arc would disappear under the custom-toolbar area. Thanks for any further valuable advice.

Comment: I could resolve problem b) as well thanks to explanations in SO 27624882. It was just a matter of definition sequence in the main layout file. Now the target is achieved and the question fully answered. My Thanks again go to Gurupad!

Comment: Good that you found solutions for further problems by yourself. If there are any further problems open a new SO thread.